# Image disappears after page finished load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I using the following code to show an image in my footer

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("Twitter-boxy-32.png"), "http://twitter.com/#!/hybrid_tech", :target => "_blank") %>
```

I saw the image for a few seconds, but after the page it's complete load, the image disappear, does any body have an idea what is the problem here???

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Chrome. It doesn't happen in Firefox or Safari.

Thanks

---

UPDATE

I don't know what is the problem. But this is how I solve.

I change the image name and the url for this

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("Twitter.png"), "http://twitter.com/hybrid_tech", :target => "_blank") %>
```

It solved my problem but I don't know why.

Comment: This is happening because of some CSS or Javascript that's running on page load. You should use firebug or similar to debug the problem and then ask a more specific question here

Comment: thanks alfonso, I check the console using chrome inspect, and It only said Failed to load resource http://localhost:3000/assets/Twitter-boxy-32.png

Comment: Ah, it might be because of the browser's cache. Try cleaning the cache and also make sure that the asset is accessible through the browser

Comment: Yes the asset is available, I already clean the cache and also restart the machine and I still have the same problem with this image, but only in chrome.

Comment: I suspect your problem was with some cached assets in rails - that would explain why changing the name of your image worked. I just had a similar problem which I solved that way. For some reason, rm-ing tmp/cache/ didn't seem to work. Anyone have thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same behavior today just after updating image files on Rails 3.2.13 + Chrome.  Pierre's comment above inspired me for my solution, thanks!  I was able to fix this issue by the following command at rails server ('$' below is bash prompt):

```
(stop rails server)
$ cd RAILS_ROOT
$ bundle exec rake tmp:clear
(restart rails server)
```

Then, reload the issued page from Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound normal. If the image is loading on page load and then disappears and considering the issue only happens on Chrome. I would suggest reviewing your JS and CSS code. Perhaps there is something there that is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve the issue by taking 2 steps:

- Resaved images as small as possible (while maintaining quality) in Photoshop under "Save for Web"
- Simplified the files names. Example: "bg-waves-autumn-texture" became "bg-waves2"

Hope that helps!